# How to use coalesced memory access

Tags: gpu, shared-memory, coalesce

I have 'N' threads to perform simultaneously on device which they need M*N float from the global memory. What is the correct way to access the global memory coalesced? In this matter, how the shared memory can help?

Answer (score 17):

Usually, a good coalesced access can be achieved when the neighbouring threads access neighbouring cells in memory. So, if `tid` holds the index of your thread, then accessing:

- `arr[tid]` --- gives perfect coalescence
- `arr[tid+5]` --- is almost perfect, probably misaligned
- `arr[tid*4]` --- is not that good anymore, because of the gaps
- `arr[random(0..N)]` --- horrible!

I am talking from the perspective of a CUDA programmer, but similar rules apply elsewhere as well, even in a simple CPU programming, although the impact is not that big there.

---

*"But I have so many arrays everyone has about 2 or 3 times longer than the number of my threads and using the pattern like "arr[tid*4]" is inevitable. What may be a cure for this?"*

If the offset is a multiple of some higher 2-power (e.g. 16*x or 32*x) it is not a problem. So, if you have to process a rather long array in a for-loop, you can do something like this:

```
for (size_t base=0; i<arraySize; i+=numberOfThreads)
    process(arr[base+threadIndex])
```

(the above asumes that array size is a *multiple* of the number of threads)

So, if the number of threads is a multiple of 32, the memory access will be good.

Note again: I am talking from the perspective of a CUDA programmer. For different GPUs/environment you might need less or more threads for perfect memory access coalescence, but similar rules should apply.

---

*Is "32" related to the warp size which access parallel to the global memory?*

Although not directly, there is some connection. Global memory is divided into segments of 32, 64 and 128 bytes which are accessed by half-warps. The more segments you access for a given memory-fetch instruction, the longer it goes. You can read more into details in the "CUDA Programming Guide", there is a whole chapter on this topic: "5.3. Maximise Memory Throughput".

*In addition, I heard a little about shared memory to localize the memory access. Is this preferred for memory coalescing or have its own difficulties?*
Shared memory is much faster as it lies on-chip, but its size is limited. The memory is not segmented like global, you can access is almost-randomly at no penality cost. However, there are memory bank lines of width 4 bytes (size of 32-bit int). The address of memory that each thread access should be different modulo 16 (or 32, depending on the GPU). So, address `[tid*4]` will be much slower than `[tid*5]`, because the first one access only banks 0, 4, 8, 12 and the latter 0, 5, 10, 15, 4, 9, 14, ... (bank id = address modulo 16).

Again, you can read more in the CUDA Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks. But I have so many arrays everyone has about 2 or 3 times longer than the number of my threads and using the pattern like "arr[tid*4]" is inevitable. What may be a cure for this?

Comment: Thank you again. Is "32" related to the warp size which access parallel to the global memory? If so, this is a trick to non-over-accessing each memory segment within this bunch of threads. Am I right? In addition, I heard a little about shared memory to localize the memory access. Is this preferred for memory coalescing or have its own difficulties?

Comment: Thank you again. I could find that for "global" memory access the coalescing (neighboring) the memory addresses which required by threads is the key while in "shared" memory the non-conflicting the addresses issued by threads is the key. Am I right?